# primeNG Datatable does not update when datasource changes

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I have an issue with primeNG datatable, when updating the datasouce the datatable does not automatically update.
I have two datatables in different components that are communicating via a service, when clicking on one row in the first datatable a method is called which updates the datasource, however the second datatable does not recognize it. 
Maybe someone had a similar issue or has an example of how to solve issues like that with primeNG datatable?
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi @Memuva welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help us help you if you could reproduce this on https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar sites so that we could check the code in an isolated context

Comment: I added a similar project here (without node modules ) https://expirebox.com/download/fd34cfeb74a86aeb4ed9cfc96f7bf7cd.html when calling the method getScriptsByMaterialnumber() in the Service the right Scripts are stored in the materialnumberScripts variable however the script.component does not recognize that the datasource -> materialnumberScripts changes

Comment: I made it work with the OnChangeEvent and a direct ParentChildRelationship between the materialnumber.component and the script.component https://expirebox.com/download/35286dc04662e4be570b6652b398482f.html , but that's not what I want, I would like to have that functionality in the Service. Does someone have a clue of how this could work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing similar issues when changing the datasource but the table doesn't changed. I posted my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587424/primeng-datatable-doesnt-refresh

Comment: @PaulMeems unfortunately no solution until now.

Comment: There was another bug filed about this here:  https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2219

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in my case:push data into tableData array, then copy tableData array itself (use `slice()`)

```
export class DataTableComponent{
    tableData=[];
    county={id:1,name:"china"}
    onAdd(){
         this.tableData.push( Object.assign({}, this.country));
         this.tableData=this.tableData.slice();
    }
}
```

and it works

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this here: [datatable issue on github](https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable/issues/10)

I tested this and works:

```
this.myDatasource = new Array;
this.myDatasource = myNewValuesFromService;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the approach of Anne, and it worked perfectly for me. The problem I had was that in service callback I was using `array[index] = new_value`, and `dataTable` would not be aware of the change.

By adding `slice()` it worked perfectly.